# How to insert a new Row in bottom of the UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use

```
func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath],
withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

method to insert a new Row in a table. But it appears from Top of the    `UITableView` (by default).

I couldn't find any option to insert rows from the bottom of the table, like on screenshot:

[image: New Rows from Bottom]

I tried use the `UIEdgeInsetsMake`:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tableView.frame.height,0,0,0)
```

but it broke all design when I scroll the table.

My question is: how to insert a new rows from bottom of the table?

**UPD:** It should looks like table moves from a keyboard View to NavigationBar when new row is added.

**UPD2:** Here is what I want: http://recordit.co/JoR7xuvvpG

I did it with the help of

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tableView.frame.height,0,0,0)
```

But contentInset adds a big white field above the rows and when I scroll down it hides added rows. Looks like they is hiding under the keyboardView. I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @raf for the suggestion:

What you need to do then, is animate the whole `UITableView` in it's parent view up as you insert elements. If you're using `autolayout`, capture the Top constraint in a property, and change it's `constant` as you insert elements. Something like:

```
 topConstraint.constant = newValue
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { 
  self.layoutIfNeeded() 
})
```

Comment: Can you give me the Objective-C  equivalent of this code ?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I can only Swift :)

Answer (score 20):

Swift 3

```
    TableView.beginUpdates()

    let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.yourArray.count - 1), section:0)

    TableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

    TableView.endUpdates()

    TableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath],
withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

It is the method for appending the rows. For inserting rows at bottom you need to give indexpath of the last row.

**For Example:**

```
var IndexPathOfLastRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.array.count - 1, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([IndexPathOfLastRow], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this does not resolved my problem. Sorry for my English, maybe I describe in wrong. Look, what I want: http://recordit.co/JoR7xuvvpG I did it with the help of: self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tableView.frame.height,0,0,0) But when I scroll down, you can see the big white field above the added rows. I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` as the row animation parameter?
Like so: (in swift)

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],   
    withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
```

Or Objective-C:

```
[self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because it's only for animation. Rows appears from the top of UITableView with .Bottom animation.
I want that rows should appears from the bottom of the table.
It should looks like a table appears from Keyboard and moves to Top when new rows is added.

Comment: Well, make sure you add to the "bottom" of your data source, and that the index of your new row is one higher than the index of the last item on the row, then.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. I want to do like this: http://recordit.co/JoR7xuvvpG

Comment: What you need to do then, is animate the whole UITableView in it's parent view up as you insert elements. If you're using autolayout, capture the Top constraint in a property, and change it's constant as you insert elements. Something like: topConstraint.constant = newValue; UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() })

Comment: looking at the video, couldn't you mess around with contentInsets to move the cell items upwards?