# How to insert a UITableViewCell at bottom with animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932050/how-to-insert-a-new-row-in-bottom-of-the-uitableview-swift)

and tried as this:

```
//UITableView 
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;

//Update the full code for the "return" key action
- (void)inputViewDidTapReturn:(MyInputView *)inputView text:(NSString *)text{
    NSLog(@"send text-----%@",text);
    [self.messageManager sendMessageTo:self.sessionID message:text  completion:^(BOOL success, Message *message) {
        if (success) {

            [self.dataArray addObject:message];

            NSIndexPath * bottomIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataArray.count-1 inSection:0];

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[bottomIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];


            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:bottomIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

        } else {
        }
    }];
}
```

But the result did not show correctly:

[image]

It started scroll from the bottom of the screen.

The `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` are both used Auto Layout and the `UITableView` is on top of the keyboard already.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Objective C**

```
[self.dataArray addObject:message];
[self.tableView reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSIndexPath *bottomIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataArray.count-1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:bottomIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
});
```

**Output**

[image]

**Swift**

```
self.dataArray.add(messasge)
self.tableView.reloadData()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let bottomIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.dataArray.count-1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: bottomIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It crashed because of beyond bounds for section.
After I add the **insert** method, it did not crash but not work either.

Comment: @Kuldeep dont you think reloadData should also be done on main thread ?

Comment: @Kuldeep It looks better but not perfect. [demo gif](https://i.loli.net/2018/09/03/5b8d1d5e63549.gif)

Comment: @magic_9527, I think you still doing something else. can you please update your question with button action code.

Comment: @Kuldeep Hi, I have updated the `UITableView` and `return function`.

Comment: @Kuldeep I have replaced in my code, the code shows up is just my original post.

Comment: @magic_9527, I have uploaded Gif, Here is Demo Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulljsibh2wl1aoa/Objective%20C%20Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Kuldeep How about use a autoLayout cell which height larger than 50 and show  s the keyboard in simulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179319/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-magic-9527).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods to insert cell into table view. First you should add the item into your array.

> `array.append(item)`

This will not update the table view yet, only the array, to add the cell into the view just call

> ```
> tableView.beginUpdates()
> tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: array.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
> tableView.endUpdates()
> ```

Comment: **1 point** OP need solution in ObjectiveC                                                                        **2 point** Your code will not move to latest inserted row automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late. Try this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).